# Separating Base and Promotional Volume

Tags: regression, time-series, arima

I am working on a project where I have to separate base and promotional volume from the sales data. I have sales data for the last 4 years at week level. How can I separate base and promotional volume from only this much data?

Is it possible to do by regression or any time series approach?
I'd appreciate any feedback.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be ARIMAX, where the promotional activity would be the additional regressors. Look at `?auto.arima` in R.

Here is an example. We simulate an ARMA(1,1) process with a nonzero mean and promotions (18 weeks without promos, followed by 2 weeks with promotions, repeated over and over for 200 weeks) and put this into a `ts` data structure with a seasonality of 52, which is almost the number of weeks per year:

```
library(forecast)
hist.promos <- rep(c(rep(0,18),rep(1,2)),10)
set.seed(2)
sales.ts <- ts(10*arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.5,ma=0.3),
    n=length(hist.promos))+60+50*hist.promos,frequency=52)
```

We model this using `auto.arima()`, feeding the historical promotions in via the `xreg` parameter:

```
model <- auto.arima(sales.ts,xreg=hist.promos)
model
```

(Note that `auto.arima()` does not recover the true model: it believes there is seasonality in there, which we didn't put in. Such is life in statistics.)

Now we can forecast using the model, using `forecast.Arima()` (note the capital A in case you want to read the help page). Note that we need to provide the *future* regressor values (i.e., promotions) via `xreg`. We calculate a baseline forecast without and one forecast with future promotions:

```
fcast.without.promos <- forecast(model,h=20,xreg=rep(0,20))
fcast.with.promos <- forecast(model,h=20,xreg=c(rep(0,18),rep(1,2)))
```

We can compare the mean forecasts (point forecasts). The difference is, of course, exactly 46.3007: the estimated coefficient from the model.

```
fcast.with.promos
fcast.without.promos
fcast.with.promos$mean-fcast.without.promos$mean
plot(fcast.with.promos)
```

[image: arima forecast]

Finally a few meta questions: do the promotions align with the week definitions, or do they run, e.g., from Wednesday to Tuesday, while the week is defined as Sunday-Saturday? Think carefully about this. In addition, think about whether you have only one type of promotion or different ones (BOGO vs. straight price reduction, advertised on TV vs. on shelf tags etc.). Finally, depending on the products, you may want to also include regressors for calendar events like Christmas and so on if `auto.arima()` and friends do not capture these effects automatically.

Comment: Promotional activities go for whole week of a particular month. Say for example, if I am in month - October, then promotion will take in the first and second week of this month. But it is not necessary that in every month promotion will happen.So in this scenario, regressors will be 0/1, where 0 corresponds to non-promo period and 1 promo period? I have never used `arimax` function. Please give your feedback

Comment: That sounds like `auto.arima()` should be pretty much what you need. You feed the regressors into the `xreg` parameter. After fitting, you can use `summary()` to examine parameter estimates, standard errors etc. This thread may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22380042/r-time-series-forecasting-with-auto-arima-and-xreg-explanatory-variables

Comment: So if I am not wrong, the coefficient of regressor will be my promotional volume?

Comment: Yes, it will be the coefficient estimate. Good luck!

Comment: The dialogue at this question may be useful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80538/marketing-mix-modeling-for-sales-data/80557#80557

Comment: @StephanKolassa : I have started my work on this approach. I got stuck at one point. I am using arimax which also allows me to   use xreg. The equations is `http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/`. How to get base volume then. Which value should be subtracted from which value. Sorry for asking so many doubts. I am very new to statistics. Please reply

Comment: @zbicyclist. Thanks for your answer. I have same doubt as above. can you explain this part?

Comment: @Nevedita: I added an example for `auto.arima()` - `arimax()` should work very similarly. I hope this helps.