# Non-fixed seasonality in time series

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality

I believe some time series data I am looking at shows seasonality according to general elections (UK, so this can be 4 or 5 years). How do I remove this effect in R?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to do something in R, but without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536).

Comment: If you expect only *local* effects in time (e.g., in the two weeks before or after the election), you can use ARIMAX models, e.g., `auto.arima()` or `arimax()` and feed dummy variables into the `xreg` parameter. This may be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90048/separating-base-and-promotional-volume If you expect something to happen over the entire election cycle, there are a couple of papers by Rob Hyndman and colleagues, e.g. this: http://robjhyndman.com/papers/complex-seasonality/

Comment: If your question is purely "which command do I use in R" this might be argued to be off topic (*which command does <x>?* is a computing question). If your question (and I read it this way) has a statistical component (more along the lines of "what's a good way to do this, and is there a nice way to do that in R?") it's on topic here. I suggest you either modify it to make the statistical aspects more explicit or (if it is purely a computing question) flag the post and ask for it to be moved to an appropriate forum.